# What's the fastest way to get to Queen Araneae?

Tags: diablo-iii

I hate the bounty for killing the spider queen. That stupid spider cavern is the worst. Is there any way you can get through it faster, or predict where things are going to be?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm glad you asked! Yes, this is one of the most predictable areas in the game.

Here's a map of this area, marked up with useful information:

[image: Marked up spider caverns map]

Firstly, look at each section that is circled. These all have 4 exits, which face upleft, upright, downleft, and downright. There are always exactly 6 of these areas in the map, and they always spawn in the same pattern. There is a single one at the entrance, then a 2x2 set of them, and then another single one by the exit.

Each possible exit you would want to check to find the correct path is marked with a check mark, and each exit that is **guaranteed to be a dead end** is marked with an X.

When you first enter, go either upright or downleft to find the first bridge. From here, you will be in the 2x2 area, where you want to check all the upleft and downright exits. This is the slowest part of the cavern, but by skipping known dead ends you can still significantly cut your time off here. Once you find the windy path, you'll know you're in the right place. As soon as you cross that path, the exit is always upright from that area.

Try it out. Enjoy the spider caverns. They're one of my favorite areas in the game because I have figured out the pattern.

Comment: Yep, spider caverns and fields of misery are quite easy once you recognize the pattern.

Comment: I can't express how much I love this answer and how much I'm glad you explaiend that. I tend to quit/rejoin when I see queen Araneae bounty since the cave drive me crazy everytime, now this time is over !

Comment: Reading this answer was like reading the first issues of Nintendo Power Magazine, where they showed the entire layout of Zelda levels and Metroid zones. Amazing, thank you!

Comment: @z- What is the pattern from Fields of Misery and what is the source of this wonderful information (Is there a website with a collection of area maps?)

Comment: @DiabloMonkey you can find the particular map here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142633/where-is-the-decaying-crypt  All the 'small' type dungeons i.e. kharza den, lost mines, scavenger's den can spawn at any of the 4 waypoint locations.  The 'big' zones like grove, crypt, etc spawn at the two large locations either bottom left or top right.  If you learn the patterns that tells you at which of the 4 locations the way point is, you can usually find the bounty target within very quickly.